# Is there a mistake in the sympy fourier_series?

Tags: sympy, continuous-fourier

Good morning,
I am trying to compute the Fourier series of f=x (periodic in 0<x<1).

I am looking at the example here:
https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/series/fourier.html#sympy.series.fourier.fourier_series
at the bottom of the page there is the following code as example

```
   from sympy import fourier_series, pi
    from sympy import *
    from sympy.abc import x
    s3 = fourier_series(x, (x, 0, 1)).truncate(10)
    p = plot(x, s3, (x, -5, 5), show=False, legend=True)
    p.show()
```

Now when I copy and paste the exact same code as that in the example I am getting a different result as that shown in the picture in the sympy manual. I am getting a series that does not follow at all the function f=x in 0<x<1.

Why is this?

Thanks

Comment: You are only calculating and plotting `s3`; so you only see a couple of lines.

Comment: s3 does not align with a triangular wave that starts at the origin. s3 passes through x=0.5;y=0 and it should not

Comment: I get exactly the same thing as the docs.

Comment: I solved the issue. I was using sympy 1.5.1. When I upgraded to sympy 1.8, it fixed it